# Can I get the Field value in String into custom TokenFilter in Apache Solr?

Tags: java, indexing, solr, lucene

I need to write a custom LemmaTokenFilter, which replaces and indexes the words with their lemmatized(base) form. The problem is, that I get the base forms from an external API, meaning I need to call the API, send my text, parse the response and send it as a `Map<String, String>` to my LemmaTokenFilter. The map contains pairs of `<originalWord, baseFormOfWord>`. However, I cannot figure out how can I access the full value of the text field, which is being proccessed by the TokenFilters.

One idea is to go through the tokenStream one by one when the LemmaTokenFilter is being created by the LemmaTokenFilterFactory, however I would need to watch out to not edit anything in the tokenStream, somehow reset the current token(since I would need to call the `.increment()` method on it to get all the tokens), but most importantly this seems unnecessary, since the field value is already there somewhere and I don't want to spend time trying to put it together again from the tokens. This implementation would probably be too slow.

Another idea would be to just process every token separately, however calling an external API with only one word and then parsing the response is definitely too inefficient.

I have found something on using the ResourceLoaderAware interface, however I don't really understand how could I use this to my advantage. I could probably save the map in a text file before every indexing, but writing to a file, opening it and reading from it before every document indexing seems too slow as well.

So the best way would be to just pass the value of the field as a String to the constructor of LemmaTokenFilter, however I don't know how to access it from the `create()` method of the LemmaTokenFilterFactory.

I could not find any help googling it, so any ideas are welcome.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public final class LemmaTokenFilter extends TokenFilter {

    private final CharTermAttribute termAtt = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

    private Map<String, String> lemmaMap;

    protected LemmaTokenFilter(TokenStream input, Map<String, String> lemmaMap) {
        super(input);
        this.lemmaMap = lemmaMap;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
        if (input.incrementToken()) {
            String term = termAtt.toString();
            String lemma;
            if ((lemma = lemmaMap.get(term)) != null) {
                termAtt.setEmpty();
                termAtt.copyBuffer(lemma.toCharArray(), 0, lemma.length());
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class LemmaTokenFilterFactory extends TokenFilterFactory implements ResourceLoaderAware {

    public LemmaTokenFilterFactory(Map<String, String> args) {
        super(args);
        if (!args.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown parameters: " + args);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public TokenStream create(TokenStream input) {
        return new LemmaTokenFilter(input, getLemmaMap(getFieldValue(input)));
    }

    private String getFieldValue(TokenStream input) {
        //TODO: how?
        return "Šach je desková hra pro dva hráče, v dnešní soutěžní podobě zároveň považovaná i za odvětví sportu.";
    }

    private Map<String, String> getLemmaMap(String data) {
        return UdPipeService.getLemma(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void inform(ResourceLoader loader) throws IOException {

    }
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure - your goal is to get the original field content, so you can send all the terms to the API as a single request, get a response back, then replace each token as they pass through the filter? Instead of reading the map for each request, you could have an static instance inside your filter class that references an object that loads it from disk when Solr starts .. but it would depend on how you plan to generate that map as well.

Comment: Exactly.However, the map is generated for each request individually, since the content of the map depends on the content of the field from the indexing Document. As I mentioned above, it's a map of `<originalWord, baseFormOfThatWord>`, which I get as a response from calling an external API depending on what I send in the request to that external API, and what I need to send is actually the content of one of the fields. To have a map like this ready on the disk, it would need to contain every possible word from my language as a key, and it's lemmatized form as a value, which is quite impossible

Answer (score 0):

---

***1. API based approach:***
You can create an Analysis Chain with the Custom lemmatizer on top. To design this lemmatizer, I guess you can look at the implementation of the [Keyword Tokenizer](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/KeywordTokenizer.java);
Such that you can read everything whatever is there inside the input and then call your API;
Replace all your tokens from the API response in the input text;
After that in Analysis Chain, use standard or white space tokenizer to tokenized your data.

***2. File-Based Approach***
It will follow all the same steps, except calling the API it can use the hashmap, from the files mentioned while defining the **TokenStream**

Now coming to the **ResourceLoaderAware**:
It is required when you need to indicate your Tokenstream that resource has changed it has **inform** method which takes care of that. For reference, you can look into [StemmerOverrideFilter](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/StemmerOverrideFilterFactory.java)

- Keyword Tokenizer: Emits the entire input as a single token.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on how to create an Analysis chain?I would need to implement my Custom lemmatizer as a Tokenizer, and I cannot use multiple Tokenizers in an analyzer chain, therefore it would end up being a single token. I cannot extend StandardTokenizer because its a final class(wanted to just add a few lines of code before `incrementToken()` method to call the API and create the map, then call `super.incrementToken()`). I guess I can create my own Tokenizer and copypaste the code from Standard Tokenizer, and just add the API call before tokenizing, but its kinda ugly

Comment: So I tried to copy-paste and change the StandardTokenizer, so before tokenizing I read all the input and call the API. However, by reading the input before tokenization, I moved the pointer to the EOF and because of that the tokenization fails(returns False from incrementToken() in the first iteration because EOF was reached). There is no way to reset the Reader, so this method does not work either.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Happy New year :) The Analysis chain in Solr is defined in the Schema.xml 
Please refer: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/analyzers.html#analyzers

<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.CustomLemmatizerFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>

So KeywordTokenizerFactory: will convert the text to one big token, and then you can use that in the CustomLemmatizerFilterFactory API call can be made,

Comment: No problem, Happy New Year to you too :) Yeah, so "analyzer chain" and only "analyzer" is the same thing, right? I'm afraid this would not work, because after I convert the text to one big token, I can call the API with it, but I loose the ability to tokenize and index these words(since I already used the keyword tokenizer and the whole text is just one big token). I need to be able to tokenize the string after I call the API and index each word in its lemmatized form.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I found the answer, or actually two answers.

One would be to write my client application in a way, that incoming requests are first processed - the field value is sent to the external API and the response is stored into some global variable, which can then be accessed from the custom TokenFilters.

Another one would be to use custom UpdateRequestProcessors, which allow us to modify the content of the incoming document, calling the external API and again saving the response so it's somehow globally accessible from custom TokenFilters. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXSK2RvVJsk) Erik Hatcher talks about the use of the ScriptUpdateProcessor, which I believe can be used in my case too.

Hope this helps to anyone stumbling upon a similar problem, because I had a hard time looking for a solution to this(could not find any similar threads on SO)

Comment: However, I have no idea how to handle the "save globally" part. If i write custom plugins, how do I code them to get the map from outside, if i need to compile it into a .jar to work with Solr. It cannot have any dependencies on my application. Is the only way to really load it from a file? This seems ineffective, because the content of the file will change before every UPDATE call to solr.